# "SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table) q" does not working on local machine

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table) q
```

does not working on my local server. it returns totally nothing (no error or empty table).

But `SELECT 1 FROM table` is ok.

What is wrong with it? is there any MySQL option for such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really being able to understand what you're wanting to achieve, the solution to this problem is:

```
SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1) q;
```

Comment: I found it. `SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table) AS q` is working. AAAASSSSS. AS on some servers matters.

Comment: AS is optional (according to MySQL 5.0 docs at least), even though the MySQL documents suggest you use AS.

Comment: did you insert a row into (the previously empty) `table` by any chance? :)

Comment: no i spend one hour for figuring this. `SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM ruch) q` does not working. `SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM ruch) AS q` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a table called "table", the SQL's fine. In my own database:

```
mysql> select 1 from (select 1 from ui_towngrpcolour) foo;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes its ok. But in my local server only `AS foo` is working. Without `AS` it is not working.